# WP_Query não funciona depois de adicionar meta_query

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho o seguinte query:

```php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page'         => '6',
    'post_type'              => 'attachment',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'galeriaimg',
            'value'     => 'sim',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$attachment = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $attachment->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $attachment->have_posts() ) {
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'medium', false );
        $img_url_full = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, 'large', false );
        echo '<a class="fancybox" href="'.$img_url_full.'">';
        echo '<img src="'.$img_url.'">';
        echo '</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<h1>ERRO1</h1>';
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Por algum motivo, depois que eu adicionei o custom field (meta key) na query, ela parou de me retornar as imagens. Já verifiquei o banco e as imagens estão relacionadas com o meta key, tudo certinho, inclusive o valor.

Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Matheus, aparentemente os argumentos da sua query estão corretos.

Caso ela ainda não esteja funcionando, experimente utilizar algum operador de comparação em um dos nós do array do meta_query (e realize testes com diferentes operadores para verificar se ocorrem mudanças no comportamento dos resultados):

```
'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'galeriaimg',
        'value'     => 'sim',
        'compare    => 'IN',
    ),
),
```

Por padrão o operador é o "=", o que já deveria resultar no seu resultado esperado.. mas faça o teste (outros operadores disponíveis [na documentação](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters))